Where does 1 in the twisting sheaf vanish?
I have a sudden confusion: $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1)$ has global sections of dimension 2, generated by $x_0$ and $x_1$. Or equivalently this bundle corresponds to a divisor $D = P\in\mathbb{P}^1$, we can embed $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1)$ to function field sheaf, and its sections are meromorphic functions with single pole allowed at $P$. So a constant function $1$ is a global section, but where does it vanish? Otherwise we would have a global trivialization $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1) \simeq \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}$. I also don't understand how $1$ in function field should be represented by $x_0$ and $x_1$ in algebraic setting.

I believe the confusion is because you are forgetting that we only have an isomorphism between the invertible sheaves $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1)$ (Serre twisting) and $\mathcal{O}(p)$ for $p \in \mathbb{P}^1$. Hence we only have an isomorphism of the corresponding vector spaces of sections depending on an isomorphism $$\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1) \simeq \mathcal{O}(p)$$
(Since we are dealing with line bundles, two different isomorphisms differ by an automorphism given by scaling and hence the same at the level of sections). For example if $p = [p_0:p_1]$, then
$$ax_0 + bx_1 \mapsto \frac{ax_0+bx_1}{p_0x_1-p_1x_0} = \frac{az+b}{p_0-p_1z}, \,\ z = \frac{x_0}{x_1}$$
is an identification you can get from the isomorphism of the above line bundles. In the above identification the constant function $1$ will correspond to $p_0x_1-p_1x_0$, which as a section of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1)$ indeed vanishes at $p$.

ahh so $1$ cannot naively thought as a function by coordinate, its appropriate coordinate representation is $p_1 - p_0z$ or $p_1w - p_0$, or $p_0x_1 - p_1x_0$ as homogeneous coordiante (since none of coordinate function is actually regular on $P^1$)
